# Detecting that a user's CloudKit storage quota has been reached - NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: swift, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

When a user's CloudKit allocations is full, sync between their devices stops working. This is fairly common considering the 5GB default. Unfortunately detecting it on the app side isn't as straightforward as one might hope.

Can someone suggest a proven solution to detect that condition when using CoreData +  NSPersistentCloudKitContainer?

Thanks